# Compatibility View issues on IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I've been stumped for days with an Issue in IE10 on Windows 8.

I am in the process of modernizing a legacy web application originally written in classic ASP to a .NET 4.0 web application.  It was originally written for IE only and began its life in IE6.  Obviously, the older pages that have not yet been updated need to use Compatibility mode but the newer pages do not need this.

Everything works as expected in IE9 -- the site is in the compatibility view list and pages display in compatibility view unless ones based off of one of the ASPX master pages containing the meta tag below are served -- then it's in "Regular" IE9 mode (verified by looking at the settings in the F12 toolbar).

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

But in IE10, the same settings are applied in the browser and the same meta tag is served (I've also tried inserting the IE10 value as well into the content attribute) but pages are shown in compatibility mode.  When breakpoints are hit, the Request.Browser.Version is showing as 7.0 and the same value is reflected in IIS logs.

Is there something else that I'm missing that's new in IE10 that needs to be added?

Comment: try adding <!DOCTYPE html> to the page

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

1. Use `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. Don't use a "X-UA-Compatible" meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```